# SSL with Android 2.2 and 2.3

Tags: android, ssl

If I hit a https url in Android 2.3, does it automatically use SSL? I'm having trouble with an application I've written between Android 2.2 and Android 2.3. When I hit the https url on Android 2.2, it bombs out and gives me the below, but when I use the same code on Android 2.3, I get nothing. So from the reading I've done around what I'm thinking is the type of certificate at this url is a type accepted by Android 2.3 by default, but not by Android 2.2, is that right?

```
05-10 13:04:37.659: WARN/System.err(2177): javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Not trusted server certificate
05-10 13:04:37.659: WARN/System.err(2177): at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:371)
05-10 13:04:37.659: WARN/System.err(2177): at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:92)
05-10 13:04:37.659: WARN/System.err(2177): at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:381)
05-10 13:04:37.659: WARN/System.err(2177): at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:164)
05-10 13:04:37.659: WARN/System.err(2177): at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
05-10 13:04:37.659: WARN/System.err(2177): at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
05-10 13:04:37.659: WARN/System.err(2177): at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:348)
05-10 13:04:37.659: WARN/System.err(2177): at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
05-10 13:04:37.659: WARN/System.err(2177): at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
05-10 13:04:37.659: WARN/System.err(2177): at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
05-10 13:04:37.667: WARN/System.err(2177): at giat.hermes.network.IntelinkConnector.connect(IntelinkConnector.java:120)
05-10 13:04:37.667: WARN/System.err(2177): at giat.hermes.view.CreateAccount$ThreadLogMeIn.run(CreateAccount.java:77)
05-10 13:04:37.667: WARN/System.err(2177): Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: TrustAnchor for CertPath not found.
05-10 13:04:37.667: WARN/System.err(2177): at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:168)
05-10 13:04:37.674: WARN/System.err(2177): at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:366)
05-10 13:04:37.674: WARN/System.err(2177): ... 11 more
05-10 13:04:37.674: WARN/System.err(2177): Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: TrustAnchor for CertPath not found.
05-10 13:04:37.698: WARN/System.err(2177): at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.java:225)
05-10 13:04:37.698: WARN/System.err(2177): at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:202)
05-10 13:04:37.698: WARN/System.err(2177): at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:164)
05-10 13:04:37.698: WARN/System.err(2177): ... 12 more
```

And I don't want to just accept all server certs

Also, if this is what's causing the problem, would it be enough to cover backwards compatibility? I'm not likely to run into this with future updates of Android right?

Comment: all your assumptions are correct.  Just like your PC, the operating system maintains a listed of "trusted certificate authorities".  The server certificate you're dealing with was issued by a CA not listed in Android 2.2.  You should expect that if supported by 2.3, that any subsequent version will also contain this same CA certificate.

Comment: and that by hitting an https url with just a regular httpPost on Android 2.3 that it uses SSL by default and handles the certificate and all that without me having to do anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want/need your app to to work with 2.2 and lower, you need to include the CA certificate in your app and set up HttpClient to trust it. You don't need to (and shouldn't) accept all certificates. As for future updates, the certificate could be removed if it is compromised, but otherwise it's unlikely.

And yes, if you are accessing an HTTPS URL, data will be sent and received using SSL (encrypted). You can capture packets to verify.

Comment: ok. That helps. I'm noticing really weird behavior. I'm only seeing this issue on an old Motorola Droid (like the first ones) running 2.2.3. A new(er) Samsung Infuse I'm using running 2.2.1 doesn't run into that issue. Since there are other capabilities that require 2.3.x, I think I'm just going to change my min SDK to be 2.3 and be done with it, since 2.3 doesn't seem to have that problem. Appreciate your help

Comment: Carriers customize the firmware, so it is very possible that the trusted certificates are different on the Droid and the Infuse. Btw, I think Motorola has a custom UI in Settings that allows you to add trusted certificates, but I am not sure in what version they introduced it. You might try to add you certificate with that if available. This tool will you allow to list trusted certificates (and add ones on a rooted device). Might be helpful for debugging: https://github.com/guardianproject/cacert